# Using std::decay with std::forward

Tags: c++, c++14, std, forward

```
template<typename T>
struct test
{
    std::string key;
    T value;
    
    template<typename U>
    using decay = typename std::decay<U>::type;

    template<typename U = decay<T>, typename US = decay<std::string>>
    test(U&& _value, US&& _key) : value(std::forward<U>(_value)), key(std::forward<US>(_key)){}
};
```

I use decay like this in my almost every project. I want ask, if its a good use instead, of writing something like this :

```
test(T&& _value, std::string&& _key) : value(std::move(_value)), key(std::move(_key)){}
test(const T& _value, std::string&& _key) : value(_value), key(std::move(_key)){}
test(T&& _value, const std::string& _key) : value(std::move(_value)), key(_key){}
test(const T& _value, const std::string& _key) : value(_value), key(_key){}
```

Comment: What is the point? Can't you just keep the template constructor and get rid of the default values and `decay`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overthink this. You need just this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct test
{
    std::string key;
    T value; // as a safety this could be replaced by:
    // typename std::decay<T>::type value;
    
    template<typename U, typename US>
    test(U&& _value, US&& _key)
       : value(std::forward<U>(_value))
       , key(std::forward<US>(_key))
    {}
};
```

This perfect forwarding will ensure that all constructors you have listed are available.

Looks like you do not understand what `std::decay` do, or when/how to use it.
Example: `decay<std::string>` is pointless, since this just represents `std::string` type, so you should write just `std::string` you do not have to do any conversion since you have full control over type passed to `decay`, you know this type doesn't contain reference or const since you have type this explicitly.

`std::decay` is useful to define a variable/filed of type which you could assign to. It strips references and constness, C-array converts to pointer, and ensures pointer to functions. See [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) example.

Could you explain what was your plan to achieve with this default types for template parameters? I can't figure out what was your intention here.

Comment: didn't know I could use template<typename U, typename US> without std::decay, thats why i used default types for template parameters. What you think in this example can i do something like template<typename T,typename U = typename std::decay<T>::type> and have U value or its pointless?

Comment: default types for template parameters are useful, when compiler is unable to deduce type, so when there is no respective argument or it is possible that argument can have default value.

Answer (score 1):

If both values are actually kept inside your class, it is much simpler than that:

```cpp
test(T value, std::string key)
    : value(std::forward<T>(value)), key(std::move(key)) {}
```